# transform a feature of a spark groupedBy DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm searching for a scala analogue of python `.transform()`

Namely, i need to create a new feature - a group mean of a corresponding: class

```
val df = Seq(
  ("a", 1),
  ("a", 3),
  ("b", 3),
  ("b", 7)
).toDF("class", "val")

+-----+---+
|class|val|
+-----+---+
|    a|  1|
|    a|  3|
|    b|  3|
|    b|  7|
+-----+---+

val grouped_df = df.groupBy('class)
```

Here's python implementation:

```
df["class_mean"] = grouped_df["class"].transform(
lambda x: x.mean())
```

So, the desired result:

```
+-----+---+----------+
|class|val|class_mean|
+-----+---+---+------+
|    a|  1|       2.0|
|    a|  3|       2.0|
|    b|  3|       5.0|
|    b|  7|       5.0|
+-----+---+----------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
df.groupBy("class").agg(mean("val").as("class_mean"))
```

If you can want all the columns then you can use window function

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("class")

df.withColumn("class_mean", mean("val").over(w))
    .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-----+---+----------+
|class|val|class_mean|
+-----+---+----------+
|b    |3  |5.0       |
|b    |7  |5.0       |
|a    |1  |2.0       |
|a    |3  |2.0       |
+-----+---+----------+
```

Comment: You can get the other column `val` by joining the original dataframe, If the column `val` or you can use window function

Comment: Ok, thanks. I really wanted to see a method of `DataFrame`

Comment: Ok, didn't it worked? or looking for something else?